# How do I update mesa 11.2.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop version? E: Unable to locate package mesa

Tags: apt, graphics, mesa

I'm trying to play Day of the Tentacle, and I need to update my Mesa driver. I have a GTX 550 Ti graphics card.

I typed in terminal:

```
glxinfo | grep "version"
```

The output was:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
Max core profile version: 4.1
Max compat profile version: 3.0
Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.1 (Core Profile) Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.10
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa
```

the output was

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mesa
```

I'm new to Ubuntu.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

mesa is the source which produces several packages of varying names. 
You can,

Wait for 16.04.2 HWE image to release, installing the various ~lts packages from it  would give you mesa 12.x. This will happen in Feb. or so.

(The HWE lts also provides some updated xserver packages & newer kernel

Or use this ppa, noting that it's providing a higher version than 16.04.2 (HWE) mesa, mesa 13.x will likely show in 16.04.3 HWE image release.

https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa

Info on the HWE for Ubuntu

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I'm going to try the ppa. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Got this AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors. Other than it seems fine.

Comment: I installed the ppa, updated, and upgraded. Still have mesa

Comment: Opps hit enter too soon. OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0 I still have Mesa 11.2.0

Comment: While I haven't tried that ppa as i've one of my own for mesa & a bit more,  I get more expected results, ex. - OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.2, ect. Did you do a restart? If so post results of `apt-cache policy libgl1-mesa-glx`

Comment: libgl1-mesa-glx:
  Installed: 11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2
  Candidate: 1:13.0.2-2~x~padoka0
  Version table:
     1:13.0.2-2~x~padoka0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 *** 11.2.0-1ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     11.2.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Does `sudo apt upgrade` show the ppa packages as an upgrade?

Comment: I'm not sure here's the output of running sudo apt upgrade. Nvm too long for comment by 7,700 some characters.

Comment: After performing sudo apt upgrade and then glxinfo | grep 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 13.0.2 - padoka PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 13.0.2 - padoka PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 13.0.2 - padoka PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10

Comment: Verified the solution works even after 15 hours and at least one restart. Thank you.